# How to create categories from a frontend form in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, categories

I want to create form on a frontend page of my website to allow assigned users to create new categories under a custom post type.
How should I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a post category in wordpress is a process that is done on the server-side. if you want to handle it by a button in client-side you should use restful api of wordpress.
it's wp'api document:

https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/categories/#create-a-category

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the bad description. I did some research and figured that's probably best solution for me